# Explanation of SQL ON

Tags: sql

I have been googled some for an explanation of the SQL function **ON** though 
I couldn't find a good explanation how it work.

is it associated/connected to **INNER JOIN**?

Could someone please explain my Code-snippet what really happens?

(see my code below)

```
SELECT
TS_TEST_ID as Test_ID,
TS_NAME as Name
FROM TEST
INNER JOIN DESSTEPS
ON  TEST.TS_TEST_ID =  DESSTEPS.DS_TEST_ID
INNER JOIN ALL_LISTS
ON ALL_LISTS.AL_ITEM_ID = TEST.TS_SUBJECT
```

Comment: Dear, what's your functional aim?

Comment: `ON` is **not** a *function*; is is **part** of the join expression.  It is SQL's version of the theta-join : `table_a JOIN table_b ON c` :=  `combine  table_a X table_b using_the_condition c` The theta notation uses infix : `table_a theta(condition) table_b`

Comment: The part of the code ON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a function, it is part of language. Like with natural language you have various types of words: like nouns, verbs etc. This is like proposition.

ON is a part of syntax for INNER JOIN, it goes like this:

```
one table INNER JOIN some other table ON how do I want to join both tables (key columns)
```

You might find some more details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 1):

`on` tells the join with which condition the tables should be connected.

In this case:

```
FROM TEST
INNER JOIN DESSTEPS
ON  TEST.TS_TEST_ID =  DESSTEPS.DS_TEST_ID
```

You tables test will be joined on column TS_TEST_ID and DS_TEST_ID. So records belong together, where These id's are equals